# Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to apply the canny function on an image and here's the full code but it shows the error only if i put the steps within a function, but doesn't show when leaving all the code outside of any functions. Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def canny(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
    canny = cv2.Canny(blur, 50, 150) #sick
    return canny

sourceimage = cv2.imread('lane.jpg')
img = np.copy(sourceimage)
canny = canny(img)
cv2.imshow("result", canny)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And here is the error i get: (python 3.6.8)

```
kream@KRIMZON:~/Desktop/finding-lanes-linux$ python3 lane.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lane.py", line 12, in <module>
    cannyer = canny(img)
  File "lane.py", line 5, in canny
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src'
kream@KRIMZON:~/Desktop/finding-lanes-linux$
```

Comment: The issue was fixed, after finding out the original image was corrupted/modified by mistake done by me after i used the variable for the original image rather than the actual copy i made of it, fixed by replacing the original image and making sure it doesn't happen again, thanks for reading.

Comment: Great that you solved it yourself :) -- but to make this useful, either write up a self-answer, or delete the question.

Comment: for some reason it doesn't let me write up a self-answer before 48 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I just run the code, it also complains `Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src'`. **Because there is no `lane.jpg` in my PC, so `cv2.imread` return `NoneType`, and `np.copy` return `np.array(None, dtype=object)`.** If you just pass such a variable to cv2, it will complain `Expected cv::UMat for argument 'xxx'`.

[image]

Yes, you should check your image exists and loaded successfully!

---

And notice, another bad practice is: **your variable name `canny` is the same with your function name `canny()`**. So when you call `canny = canny(img)`, the function `canny()` object is replaced by variable `canny`. If you call `canny()` next time, it will fail like this:`TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`.
[image]

Then use different names.

---

```
>>> src = cv2.imread("noexist.png")
>>> img = np.copy(src)
>>>
>>> type(src)
<class 'NoneType'>
>>> cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.1) d:\build\opencv\opencv-4.0.1\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

>>>
>>> img
array(None, dtype=object)
>>> cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src'
>>>
>>> img()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```